# Couldn't find User without an ID, tried everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble creating an edit link using a nested resource.  My account has many users and I'd like to create an edit link to the user from the account show page.  Below is my account show view, account controller.  Any help you could provide would be fantastic.  Thank you.

Account/View/Show

```
<h2>Users</h2>
    <% @account.users.each do |f| %>
     <% next if f.name.nil? %>

      <p>
        <%= link_to f.name, edit_account_user_path(@user.account, @user) %>
     </p>
```

Account Controller Show

```
  def show
   @user = @account.users.find(params[:account_id])
   account = Account.find(params[:account_id])

  end
```

Routes

```
  resources :accounts
  resources :users

  resources :accounts do
  resources :users 
   end
```

Account Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Comment: One caveat about `nil?` on model attributes. One tends to store a blank string into the database when the form field is blank thus `nil?` would return true. `<% next if f.name.blank? %>` is more appropiate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an edit link within an iterator and you have `f` as the variable that refers to each `user` related to `@account`.

So you should have something like this instead -

```
<% @account.users.each do |f| %>
 <% next if f.name.nil? %>

  <p>
    <%= link_to f.name, edit_account_user_path(@account, f) %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <smacks head>  OMG.  It's always something so small and silly for me.  Your solutions works perfectly.  Thank you @dkp!!!

Comment: Good except for naming, this `f` should be `user`.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll   yes, `user` would make more sense than `f`. I just let it be like that because `f` was there in question .